# Drupal 10 - global-styling library does not works properly

Tags: drupal, configuration, yaml, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a starter theme for Drupal 10, I based my theme on the [Drupal 10 starterkit](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-themes/starterkit-theme), and I want to add tailwind to all pages of my project. So I created a really simple tailwind configuration. I followed all Drupal 10 steps but I don't know why my dist/index.css file is absolutely not reached by my website.

**`custom_theme.info.yml`**

```
name: custom_theme
type: theme
'base theme': stable9
starterkit: true
version: VERSION
libraries:
  - custom_theme/global-styling
  - custom_theme/base
  - custom_theme/messages
  - core/normalize
libraries-extend:
  user/drupal.user:
    - custom_theme/user
  core/drupal.dropbutton:
    - custom_theme/dropbutton
  core/drupal.dialog:
    - custom_theme/dialog
  file/drupal.file:
    - custom_theme/file
  core/drupal.progress:
    - custom_theme/progress
core_version_requirement: ^10
generator: 'starterkit_theme:10.1.7'
```

**`custom_theme.libraries.yml`**

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      dist/index.css: {}
# ...
```

No special configuration on my Drupal website, is a fresh Drupal 10.1.7, but I have to precise my theme is part of an installation profile, maybe it has an importance I don't know...

Thanks for your help !

I try to recreate a theme from scratch, rename my theme, and flush caches many times...

Comment: check in the browser at what location the css file needs to be placed and is it publicly available or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put index.css in dist folder?